# How to add participants to XMPP chat room in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xmpp, ejabberd

I want to add participants in existing group. For this I pass participant's Affiliation as owner and Role as moderator.

**I am testing on "conference.jabber.org".** I created room successfully but when I go to add some participants in that room it gives error

```
"error code=\"405\" type=\"cancel\">  not-allowed xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas\" /></error>"
```

Please help.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add users to a chat room directly; you can invite them, but they have to explicitly join by themselves.  (Though you should be able to modify their affiliation regardless of whether they're in the room or not, and if they are in the room you should be able to change their role to moderator.)

There are two methods for inviting participants.  [One involves sending the invite through the chat room](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#invite-mediated):

```xml
<message
    from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='nzd143v8'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <invite to='hecate@shakespeare.lit'>
      <reason>
        Hey Hecate, this is the place for all good witches!
      </reason>
    </invite>
  </x>
</message>
```

and [the other involves sending a message directly to the user you're inviting](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0249.html):

```xml
<message
    from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    to='hecate@shakespeare.lit'>
  <x xmlns='jabber:x:conference'
     jid='darkcave@macbeth.shakespeare.lit'
     password='cauldronburn'
     reason='Hey Hecate, this is the place for all good witches!'/>
</message>
```

Comment: Thank you @Legoscia for reply. But I just wanted to know that how Wats App works? Suppose, If I create a group and add some friends then it wont ask for invitation. It directly add them into created group.

Just like this I don't want to invite my friend but want to add them directly.

Please suggest me any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess either the client automatically accepts the invitation, or their system uses something else than standard MUC as defined by XEP-0045.

Comment: please tell me one thing, **how can I set any user as admin or owner of the room?**

Can you share that iq or xml?

Comment: There are examples for that in [section 10.3 (for owner)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#grantowner) and [section 10.6 (for admin)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#grantadmin) of XEP-0045.

Comment: Thanks again @legoscia. It works. Now I want to get all users information of room like their role and affiliation.
Please tell me how could i do this.
Thanks.

Comment: one more thing. I want to get only private groups or rooms which i created?

Because when i get rooms using this xml it gives me whole public groups.
> @"<query xmlns=""http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"" node=""http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#rooms""/>"

Please suggest me how can i get private rooms from "conference.jabber.org".

Thanks

Comment: - Hi @legoscia, Do you have any idea about previous comment?? Please tell me how can i get private rooms?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. You could try asking a new question; that would give you more visibility.